# In Polymer 3, double click event is not working. ex: @on-dblclick="${this.dblclicked}"

Tags: progressive-web-apps, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

How to use double click event in polymer 3 I don't want to use custom double tap. 
Below is my code which is not working.

```
import { html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
import { PageViewElement } from './page-view-element.js';
import { SharedStyles } from './shared-styles.js';
class MyView1 extends PageViewElement {
  render() {
    return html
      ` ${SharedStyles}
      <section>
      <input type='text' @on-dblclick="${this.dblclicked}"/>
      </section>  `;
  }
  dblclicked() {
  }
}
window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1); `
```

Comment: Have you tried `on-dbclick="{{this.dblclicked}}"` binding?

Answer (score 1):

At Lit-Element on-dblclick event's usage is ;

```
 <input type='text' value="Double Click Me" @dblclick="${this.dblclicked}"/>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5opp1g?file=index.js)